# history attribute in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was reading about **Time-Based** Versioned Graphs and came across the following example:

```
CREATE (s1:Shop{shop_id:1})
  -[:STATE{from:1388534400000,to:9223372036854775807}]->
  (ss1:ShopState{name:'General Store'})
```

My question: how do I calculate this date? `from:1388534400000,to:9223372036854775807`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two values are timestamps which in java are the number of milliseconds since the Epoch (1/1/1970) began. The second value is the maximum Long value, the end of Java time, a long way away.

There are ways in all languages for generating these values for specific dates (beware that some will be based on seconds), there is quite a handy list on [this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

If you are not working in any particular programming language and just want to enter queries then you can use an online date converter like [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm).

You can also calculate timestamps in Cypher if you are working with dates that relate to `Now` somehow using the `timestamp()` function:

```
CREATE (s1:Shop{shop_id:1})
-[:STATE{from:timestamp(),to:9223372036854775807}]->
(ss1:ShopState{name:'General Store'})
```

Comment: 9223372036854775807 represents EOT in general?

Comment: Yes Sunday, August 17th in the year 292278994 at 7:12:55 in the morning, GMT.

Comment: I guess the original example was saying the store is open until further notice.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `to` is just a `Long.MAX_VALUE`, and `from` can be a result of either calling `timestamp()` function via Cypher or setting the property with the value of `System.currentTimeMills()` via Java API.

Take a look at the example: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=43uoyt (Note that you can skip setting `rel.to` and use `coalesce` when querying instead).